# How to modify the csv feed file in gatling

Tags: scala, csv, gatling

I have a user.csv file like this:

```
user, password
userid1, password1
```

I want to decrypt the password in the csv file.
One way is `.feed(csv("user.csv"))` and then

```
.exec(session => {
        val pwd = session("password").as[String]
        session.set("password", decrypt(pwd))//some function to decrypt the password
      })
```

Now I want to decrypt the password before feed the csv file. Is there any way to do that in Gatling?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're after... calling feed is what gets the password (encrypted) value from the csv. Are you talking about storing the decrypted values in the csv?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add a conversion to a feeder definition with a function that will convert a given value.

https://gatling.io/docs/current/session/feeder/#converting

looks like your use-case